# Asynchronous callback not invoked during test using Mockito

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, timeout, mockito

I am trying to test application using Mockito Framework. Following example works perfectly:

```
    val dl = mock(classOf[DichListener])
    val i = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(classOf[Int])
    when(dl.test(i.capture())).thenCallRealMethod()
    dl.test(666)
    i.getValue shouldBe 666
```

However, very similar (but waiting for asynchronous response), next one doesn't:

```
    when(dl.echoReqCallback(c.capture(), m.capture())).thenCallRealMethod()
    // Also not working:
    // verify(dl).echoReqCallback(c.capture(), m.capture())

    n2.sendEchoRequest("hello!")

    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(m.getValue)
```

`echoReqCallback` is called after `sendEchoRequest`, `dl` is mocked object. `echoReqCallback` is run as a response to network message, so it could not invoke immediately after line:

```
n2.sendEchoRequest("hello!")
```

I tried using much longer `sleep` time, but result is always the same: my callback method is not invoked thus `m` variable didn't get any value.

Log:
using `verify`:

```
> [info]   org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked:
> Wanted but not invoked:                                            
> [info] dichListener.echoReqCallback(                                  
> [info]     <Capturing argument>,                                      
> [info]     <Capturing argument>                                       
> [info] );
```

using `when`:

```
> [info]   org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: No argument
> value was captured!                                               
> [info] You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in
> verify()...                                                           
> [info] ...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not
> called.                                                        [info]
> Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()   
> [info]                                                                
> [info] Examples of correct argument capturing:                        
> [info]     ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument =
> ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);                                
> [info]     verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());              
> [info]     assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

**EDIT:**
`n1` is connected to `n2`. I want to send Echo_Request from `n2` to `n1` and check if listener (`dl`) which I attach after mocking to `n1` (`n1.listener = dl`) will fire `echoReqCallback`. Logic is working beneath testing code.

Comment: You haven't given us anywhere near enough information to diagnose your problem.  But it seems that `dl` is the object that you're testing.  If that is the case, why are you mocking it?  Or did I misunderstand what you're doing?

Comment: That is correct. I believe I need to mock object before I can use it in `when` method. `dl` runs method `echoReqCallback` for sure, I can see debug messages, but captured variables are empty, `m` and `c`.

Comment: You don't need the "when" if all you're doing is making it call the real method.  You mock an object because you want it to behave differently from how an unmocked one would.  But that makes your test invalid.  It's usually a bit pointless to test an object whose behaviour you've changed by mocking.  In short, don't mock the object that you're trying to test.

Comment: well, actually I would like to create some callback instead of dummy "sleep" to test network connection.

Comment: So which class has the callback method?

Comment: `DichListener` has callback which invocation I want to detect.

Comment: So the purpose of your test is to ensure that when you call `sendEchoRequest` on a `DichListener`, then `echoReqCallback` is called on the same object?  Or a different object?  Sorry, I'm having trouble following all these tiny little snippets of code, without seeing the big picture.

Comment: I use `sendEchoRequest` on `n2` object, then I am waiting for `ReqCallback` on listener object, which is in different class.

Comment: So you're actually testing whatever class `n2` is?  How does `n2` know which object to call `echoReqCallBack` on?

Comment: @DavidWallace thanks for interest, I edited question to describe code more.

Comment: OK, entertain me.  What happens if you add `verify(dl).echoReqCallback(any(), any())` to the end of your test?

Comment: I can't run it now, but I tried `any()` for sure... and nothing good happend : )